# How to avoid infinite loop while updating self in a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: rxjs, observable

Declared like this:

```
  public panel$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
```

Used like this

```
  togglepanel() {
    this.panel$.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        if (x) {
          this.panel$.next(false);
        } else {
          this.panel$.next(true);
        }
      });
  }
```

It creates an endless cycle trying to update self.

Comment: Why you need to update `panel$` in its own subscribe callback?

Comment: ok then I dont know the usual way to toggle, tell  me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update it by taking only  one(latest) value from the `panel$` Observable:

```
this.panel$.take(1).subscribe(...)
```

But it is better to model your state a bit differently, like this:

```js
// const onToggle$ = new Rx.Subject();
var toggle$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');

const initialValue = true;
const state$ = toggle$
  .scan(state => !state, initialValue)
  .startWith(initialValue);
      
const htmlSubscription = state$.subscribe(state => {
  document.getElementById('toggle').innerText = 'toggle: ' + state;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">loading...</button>
```

EDIT:

Angular version of this code is:

```
  public toggle$ = new Subject();
  public state$ = this.toggle$.scan(state => !state, true)
                        .startWith(true)
                        .subscribe((x) => console.log('x:' + x));


  togglepanel() {
    this.toggle$.next(null);
  }
```

Comment: where will I place the above code. I need a onToggle() function to call

Comment: (I've updated code snippet). You can push value `onToggle$.next(...)` to the Subject from your `onToggle` function

Comment: actually I am using angular, sorry I missed mentioning that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it doesn't matter. Just replace click events Observable with your angular stuff and it will work

Comment: not clear to me, what should I subscribe in `toggle()` ?

Comment: Nothing. You should call `onToggle$.next(null);` and it will change current toggle state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160334/discussion-between-ishandutta2007-and-oles-savluk).

Comment: I need to print
so I tried this
```public toggle$ = new Subject(); 
public state$ = this.toggle$.scan(state => !state, true) 
.startWith(true) 
.do((x) => console.log('x:' + x));```
but nothing happens